# In Ubuntu Studio, what is the name of the auto-hide panel at the bottom?

Tags: ubuntu-studio

How would I add it to another distro with XFCE?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's just an XFCE panel with auto-hide enabled, like in Xubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

A comprehensive list of docks is available as answers to this question: [What docks are available?](https://askubuntu.com/q/8865/9598)

I can't say which one is Ubuntu Studio using at the moment and it will be useful if you drop an image as an edit to your question in order to identify it thus provide a workaround for installing in XFCE.

Nevertheless, the already provided answers in the mentioned question are very illustrative and they also includes a way to install in the majority on the Ubuntu based systems (xUbuntu, LUbuntu, etc.)

Good luck!