# Install Themes and Icons from Elementary OS without pantheon

Tags: themes, icons, dock, elementary

I know [How to install the Pantheon desktop environment?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66757/how-to-install-the-pantheon-desktop-environment), but I'd rather not install the whole desktop environment but only the theme and iconset.

I can install [Cairo dock](http://glx-dock.org/) That looks alike Plank (the docker used in Elementary OS):

```
sudo apt-get install cairo-dock
```

(some more docks [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/8866/34298))

Is there an easy way to get the theme and icons from Elementary OS on Ubuntu Unity desktop on Ubuntu 14.10?

Comment: You should be able to search elementary like icons in gnome-look.org, ubuntu mono icons are based itself on elementary icons.

Answer (score 2):

1. Add Elementary ppa:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/stable
   ```
2. Update your system:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
3. Install the icon theme:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install elementary-icon-theme
   ```

Comment: If you have Ubuntu 14.10, you get `http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu/dists/utopic/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found` so this helps: `sed -i s/utopic/trusty/g elementary-os-ubuntu-stable-utopic.list`

Comment: No I get `The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 elementary-icon-theme : Depends: gnome-icon-theme-full but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems`

Comment: So since there is no repository for 14.10 or 15.04 I guess **this is only a solution for 14.04**

Comment: Try ppa:elementary-os/daily

Comment: On 14.10 with daily I get the error `elementary-icon-theme : Depends: gnome-icon-theme-full but it is not going to be installed` and if I try `apt-get install elementary-icon-theme gnome-icon-theme-full` then I get: `gnome-icon-theme-full : Depends: gnome-icon-theme (= 3.10.0-0ubuntu2) but 3.12.0-1ubuntu1 is to be installed`

Comment: It seems that the only option left is installing from noobslab repositories. (noobslab.com)

Comment: Can't i just download the icons and unpack them in some folder so i can use them? Or install another theme and replace the icons with the one from that package?

Comment: protip: you can use the newer `apt` instead of `apt-get`, it's nicer and shorter