# Lock programs in menu bar

Tags: launcher, menu, lock

I'm currently running Ubuntu v. 14.04 and I was wondering if it is possible to lock programs to the menu bar like you can to the launcher. Ultimately I would like to have launcher icons in the upper right of the menu bar (next to wifi, time, etc.). Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

No, on a standard Ubuntu install, it is not possible to do this.

There is the `classicmenu-indicator` which you could install and run, to provide the traditional menu as an indicator in the upper right. Due to the nature of the menu panel though, traditional launchers as would have existed on the GNOME 2.x panel would not work, as they would have to open a menu, where you could then launch the thing from, and that kind of defeats the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with Ubuntu 14.04 (with Unity), but you might want to try [a "dock" software](https://askubuntu.com/q/8865/58950).